# all possible combinations in javascript - why pop()?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to understand this function that I came across online that returns all possible combinations of a string -- why exactly is the pop() call needed with nextLetter.pop? I tried debugging this in the console but it's not clear what the pop does exactly.

result with nextLetter.pop() ---> [ 'bac', 'bca', 'cba', 'cab', 'acb', 'abc' ]

result without nextLetter.pop() --> [ 'bac',
  'bacca',
  'baccacba',
  'baccacbaab',
  'baccacbaabacb',
  'baccacbaabacbbc' ]

```
function stringPermutations(str) {
  var permutations = [];
  var nextLetter = [];
  var chars = str.split('');

  permutateInner(chars);



  function permutateInner(chars) {
    if (chars.length === 0) {

      permutations.push(nextLetter.join(''));
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {


      chars.push(chars.shift());

      nextLetter.push(chars[0]);

      permutateInner(chars.slice(1));
      //what is this doing?

      nextLetter.pop();

    }
  }
  return permutations;
}

console.log(stringPermutations('abc'));
```

Comment: javascripts Arrays `pop` method only removes the last element from array,  and returns that element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`permutateInner(chars.slice(1));` does recursion on array subset `[1..n]`. It is included to have permutation also for each subarray of current array.

e.g. when current first letter is `b`, recursion includes permutations `ac` and `ca`. when current first letter is `a`, recursion includes permutations `cb` and `bc`.

It is crucial to have it there, otherwise you would get only result [ 'abc', 'bca', 'cba' ]

Answer (score 0):

Starting at the top, it's clear that `nextLetter` is an `Array` -- so the first place I'd look would be the [docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop).

As the documentation says, the `.pop()` method removes the last element from the `Array` and returns it -- in your sample code the return value isn't being used, so clearly what's useful is the side effect of removing the last element.

Comment: I understand what pop itself does, but not what it's doing in the context of recursion inside the for loop